# Data labels in spreadsheet gear 2012

Tags: label, spreadsheetgear

I am trying to make the series name in a bar chart show up as a Data Label in spreadsheetgear 2012 but cannot find a way to make it visible in the chart explorer.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

While the ChartExplorer allows you to modify many aspects of a chart, it does not yet support modifying data label related chart elements.

Instead, you'll need to use SpreadsheetGear API to do this, which would involve enabling ISeries.[HasDataLabels](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.Charts.ISeries~HasDataLabels.html) and then fine-tuning how the labels are displayed with ISeries.[DataLabels](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.Charts.ISeries~DataLabels.html) (see [IDataLabels](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.Charts.IDataLabels_members.html) interface).  Example:

```
// Assuming you have an IChart object named "chart", enable
// data labels for the first series.
chart.SeriesCollection[0].HasDataLabels = true;
```